# Low connection window.location.href

Tags: javascript

I have a call of `window.location.href='url_value'` but I have the case when the connection speed is very very low and the target resource very hard. I need to specify how much time we waiting before we solved resource is not available. I need to set 1 minute. How todo that? Thank you.

Comment: Timeout is specified by the server. Do you control the server?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev That's not entirely true, your browser also has a timeout that is set before giving up due to poor connection as OP describes. But that cannot be changed by JavaScript either.

Comment: Once you tell browser to go somewhere else....nothing you can do to abort it yourself

Comment: @Slava Knyazev no I can't control the server.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing window.location, you can add a timeout to ajax for handling these.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url_value",
    error: function() {
        // when timeout
    },
    success: function() {
        // replace html
    },
    timeout: 60 * 1000
});
```

If not using jQuery, you may attach a timeout to xhr by using:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'url_value', true);
xhr.timeout = 60 * 1000; 
xhr.ontimeout = function() { // error }
```

Comment: Using JQuery for this is overkill

Comment: You are right, also added how to handle it using the vanilla xhr.

Comment: Also assumes that url isn't on a different domain that would cause CORS issues

Comment: @charlietfl Why would you assume otherwise? This solves the issue for same origin, if what you describe is the situation, then it's impossible. There is nothing wrong with this answer.